# Change the uri of a module without renaming the class in PyroCMS

Tags: php, codeigniter, pyrocms

What is the best way to change the uri of a module without renaming the class. For example I'd like the blog module to show:

/**blog**/post-title  ->  /**news**/post-title

routes.php?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First I added to the routes.php.

> $route['news/([0-9]+)/([0-9]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)'] = 'blog/$1/$2/$3';

Then to make sure the correct links I added this to the blog plugin.php.

```
foreach ($posts as &$post)
{
    $post->url = str_replace('blog/', 'news/', $post->url);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The best way is to use the routes module.

If you don't want to use it, modify the `routes.php` in `cms/config` and not in your module because it won't run under a different path.

Comment: I also have to add this to the blog plugin.php to make sure the links go to the correct location.

Comment: foreach ($posts as &$post)
        {
            $post->url = str_replace('blog/', 'news/', $post->url);
        }