# Change name url from blog page pyrocms

Tags: pyrocms

I want change page name on blog module..

I need that it shows like a "news"

Example:

/blog/post-title -> /news/post-title

Comment: This has been asked before: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10899376/change-the-uri-of-a-module-without-renaming-the-class-in-pyrocms

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways to do this.

The first is to duplicate the blog module as news.
See the following Gist script: https://gist.github.com/3949038

The second is to create a route to redirect `blogs` to `news`.
See: 
[Change the uri of a module without renaming the class in PyroCMS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10899376/change-the-uri-of-a-module-without-renaming-the-class-in-pyrocms)